# How to make a video from images using ffmpeg

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python in a jupyter notebook, and I am trying to make a video out of several images. I have a folder called 'images', and within that file the images are labeled 'image0', 'image1','image2', etc.
I have installed ffmpeg successfully, and then tried:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i images/image_%d.bmp -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

I am getting a syntax error, and I am not sure if I am getting all of the images correctly. Can this line be done in a notebook? Thank you!

Comment: You should always show the actual error messages. Otherwise we have to either guess or ask for the error. Most informative and helpful is to provide the **complete** log from your command.

Comment: Read [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) guide on how to make a video slideshow from your images